# How to allow registered users on offline site

Tags: joomla-3.x, joomla-2.5, permissions

When putting my Joomla site in offline mode, only Super Users can log in and view the site:

[image: Offline mode]

How can I allow registered users to log in and see the site even in offline mode, without giving them Super user privileges?

Answer (score 11):

To control what user groups have access to an offline site, go to Global Configuration (**System** -> **Global Configuration**) and select the **Permissions** tab. Select the user group you want to give access on the right hand side (in this case "Registered"), and set **Offline Access** to "Allowed". (Default setting is "Inherited", thus *Not Allowed*. Save. Your registered users will now be able to log in even if your site is offline.

[image: Permission settings]